# stripslashes not working when insert into database table

Tags: php, mysql

when i try to run this code :

```
<?php
$str = "Patty O'Furniture";
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    echo stripslashes($str);
?>
```

the output is `Patty O'Furniture`  but when i try to run this code(upload data into database table)

```
<?php
if ($_FILES[csv][size] > 0) {

    //get the csv file
    $file = $_FILES[csv][tmp_name];
    $handle = fopen($file,"r");

    //loop through the csv file and insert into database
    do {
        if ($data[0]) {
            if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO sms_recipient (store_id, recipient_name, recipient_phone) VALUES
                (
                    '".$login_id."',
                    '".stripslashes($data[0])."',
                    '".stripslashes($data[1])."'
                )
            ");
        }
    } while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'"));
    //
}
?>
```

the output only `Patty O` . (see screenshot)

[image]

i'm not sure why when i try to save data into database using function `stripslashes` it's not working.

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient mysql_* functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're undoing what [magic_quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc) is trying to do.

> When magic_quotes are on, all ' (single-quote), " (double quote), \
>   (backslash) and NUL's are escaped with a backslash automatically.

So you're removing the backslashes via `stripslashes` that are being added, and shorting the query when it hits the `'` in `O'Furniture`

Answer (score 0):

use [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) function instead of `stripslashes()`

or

Try to avoid `mysql_*` functions, Try to use [`mysqli`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or `PDO`

Comment: already replace with this mysql_real_escape_string() but again when perform insert into database script the result is still same .

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is the basis for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Your input is not escaped at all once you remove the slashes. Imagine what would happen if an attacker provided an input string that closed your query and began a new one with `'; UPDATE users SET password WHERE username="admin"`?

At the very least, you need to escape your input with `mysql_real_escape_string`, but really you need to stop using the `mysql` extension. Use prepared statements of the `mysqli` extension instead.